# Redirect all URLs except one in lighttpd

Tags: redirection, url, lighttpd

How can I use `mod_redirect` in lighttpd to redirect all URLs  except one to another URL?

**Example**

`www.dontredirect.com` would not be redirected at all, but all other URLs like `www.foo.com` or `www.another.co.uk` would be redirected to lets say `www.redirected.com`

Answer (score 1):

http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/docs_modredirect

```
$HTTP["host"] !~ "^(www\.)?dontredirect\.com.*$" {
    url.redirect = (
      "^/(.*)" => "http://www.redirected.com/$1" 
    )
}
```

Not too difficult, reading the above page would have taken only 1 minute. google is your friend.